# postgres- how to cascade temporary delete

Tags: postgresql

postgres like many other databases has an option to specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` which lets us cascade the deletion of a referencing row in the child table if the corresponding row in the parent table has been deleted.

But, often times, we like performing only soft deletes, where we make the data in the tables logically deleted by setting a flag such as `is_deleted` to true.  Is setting a trigger the only option that we have to manage this? Or is there a more concise and manageable way to do this in postgres?

Comment: First the term `soft delete` is a non sequitur, either the data still exists or it does not. What you are actually doing is changing the status of a record. Since the record will still exist(not be deleted) `ON DELETE CASCADE` will not work. You will need to use trigger to achieve what you want.

Comment: In addition to Adrian, why don' t use `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`. Later, with a batch job you can perform "hard delete" if those columns that' s referenced columns are set NULL or default value.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN , is a solution such as `ON DELETE SET custom_function()` possible? `custom_function()` would return a value to be populated in the specific cell

Comment: @AdrianKlaver , is a solution such as `ON DELETE SET custom_function()` possible? `custom_function()` would return a value to be populated in the specific cell

Comment: No, but as Adrian set you can use trigger `BEFORE | AFTER DELETE` trigger.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The solution is a trigger.